# Adding constraint to ensure diagonals of a complex matrix are equal?

Tags: python, matrix, cvxpy

I'm trying to solve a convex minimzation problem using the CVXPY module in Python. I want to solve for a complex matrix X of dimension d*d and add the Constraints, that
trace (A * X) = 1 for a given matrix A and
X is positive semdefinite, hermitean and all diagonal entries of X are equal to one another.

I added the first 3 Constraints into my Code by

```
X = cp.Variable((d,d), complex = True)
constraints = [X >>0, cp.trace(A @ X) == 1]
```

Does anyone have any idea how to add the last constraint, that all diagonal elements are equal?

Comment: Can't you declare that `X` is PSD?  Why impose that constraint later?

Comment: I can only add one attribute in the declaration of my variable X, so i was thinking i had to add the fact that X is complex.

Comment: Just add the constraints one by one (X[i,i]==X[0,0]) or use cp.diag()

Comment: Thank you, I added the constraint by cp.diag(X) == X[0,0] * np.ones(d)